# do-while loops annual increase

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

I have been working on this assignment for over 4 hours and it is due in 2 hours and I am just getting further back now. I had it actually outputting the first year correct, but all the other years weren't. I have been working on it so much I can't even get it to work now, I am just getting errors.

A health club currently charges $250.50 a year for membership. It has announced that it will increase its membership fee by 2% each year for next 7 years.

Write a program that uses a do-while loop to display the current rate, and then the projected rates for the next 7 years. Start at year=0, meaning the current year. The following should be the display. 
Hint 1: Create a double variable charges and initialize it with the first year membership. Inside the loop, update charges by adding 2% to it.
Hint 2: Use  header, setprecision(2), fixed  and setw() options.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    const string ID = "Matthew Valdez - CS1361-D10 - Assignment 25";
    double membership,
        years = 1,
        initialMembership = 250.50,
        membershipIncrease = .02;


    cout << ID << endl << endl;
    cout << "Year Charges" << endl;
    cout << "------------" << endl;
    {
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
        cout << left << setw(5) << "0" << initialMembership << right << setw(5) << endl;
    }
    do
    {
        cout << left << setw(5) << years++ << initialMembership *= membershipIncrease << right << setw(5) << endl;
   } while (years < 8);
   return 0;

}
```

The error I am getting is expression must have integral or unscope enum type and <<: illegal left operand has type "double"

Answer (score 0):

You are running into problems due to operator precedence.

Since `<<` has higher precedence than `*=`, the line

```
cout << left << setw(5) << years++ << initialMembership *= membershipIncrease << right << setw(5) << endl;
```

is equivalent to

```
(cout << left << setw(5) << years++ << initialMembership) *= (membershipIncrease << right << setw(5) << endl);
```

which is far from what you intended to do.

Make your code simpler by splitting that statement into two.

```
initialMembership *= membershipIncrease;
cout << left << setw(5) << years++ << initialMembership  << right << setw(5) << endl;
```

This is a personal preference but you don't need to increment `year` in the same line. You can use:

```
initialMembership *= membershipIncrease;
cout << left << setw(5) << years << initialMembership  << right << setw(5) << endl;
++years;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had the calculation wrong but I was able to fix it after what you had said.   
 }
 do
 {
  initialMembership = initialMembership + (initialMembership * membershipIncrease);
  cout << left << setw(5) << years << initialMembership << right << setw(5) << endl;
  ++years;
 } while (years < 8);
 return 0;